# ARRAYFORMULA with repetition

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have two columns of data, and would like to distribute the elements of one of these columns over several rows. I can easily calculate the index of the element I need, but cannot figure out how to access the element.

```
A    B   Desired output  Formula for index: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A,CEILING(ROW(A:A)/3+1),""))
1    11       22                  2
2    22       22                  2
3    33       22                  2
4    44       33                  3
5             33                  3
6             33                  3
7             44                  4
```

How can I modify my formula for the index so that it yields the item of column B at the calculated index?

I tried `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A, INDEX(B:B, CEILING(ROW(A:A)/3+1), 1), ""))` but that only repeats the first element (22) 7 times.

Comment: How about using an Index formula in the column C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Vlookup instead of Index:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A,vlookup(CEILING(ROW(A:A)/3+1),A:B,2),""))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

It isn't necessary to use a key column, you could use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(vlookup(CEILING(sequence(counta(B:B)*3)/3+1),{row(B:B),B:B},2))
```

assuming you wanted to generate three rows for each non-blank row in column B not counting the first one.

Or if you want to be different, use a concatenate/split approach:

```
=ArrayFormula(flatten(split(rept(filter(B:B,B:B<>"",row(B:B)>1)&"|",3),"|")))
```

(all the above assume you want to ignore the first row in col B and start with 22).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible without using a key column? I would like to be able to change 'A' without the formula breaking down... But if it's not possible, I'll just use a separate key column. I wonder why Index does not work, it should be made for this task.

Comment: Do you mean, to generate 12 rows in the case shown (because there are four rows in column B), without putting numbers in column A? The answer should be 'yes' and can add to my answer. One of the differences from Excel - there you can coerce Index to generate an array, but in Google Sheets you can't.

Comment: I meant the first -- generate 7 rows, but do not rely on the values in A to stay the same. But thanks for your second one too -- something to learn here!